# Send complex View by email, wihout loosing layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I created an web application which displays few Telerik charts in a form of Dashboard. There are also some javascript code for animation and events. Now I've been asked if this Dashboard could be send via email. Which I through should be easy task, but after spending 3 days I have run out of ideas how to do it. 
So I have tried to use:

- MVCMailer with PreMailer.Net
- Make a screenshot of the View and send it as an email

Do you know how can I send my Dashboard via email?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the final rendered HTML code for the page you could send it but the thing I've found with emails is that the HTML code has to be very specific and usually uses a lot of legacy tags.

Modern CSS/HTML just won't be supported and won't look as you expect. JavaScript and animation will also be a no no.

That's not to say you could take say `chart a` and `chart b` from your site and embed them in a set email layout. The only issue you might have is lack of flexibility with the rendered code from Telerik.

Edit (forgive me if I'm not fully understanding Telerik's workings):

For HTML as a string, perhaps you could render the HTML (& JS) via a HTMLhelper in the controller itself. This way should result in the final HTML code...
You would create the controller method and view as normal but the code below would give you the final rendered HTML.

```
HtmlHelper helper = new HtmlHelper(new ViewContext(ControllerContext, new WebFormView(ControllerContext, "Index"), 
            new ViewDataDictionary(), new TempDataDictionary(), new StringWriter()), new ViewPage());

MvcHtmlString yourViewHTML = System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(helper, "TheViewName", new
        {
            param1 = "test" 
        });
```

You'll then have "yourViewHTML" as a HTML string to pass to an email.

Comment: I understand that I will probably ended up with creating separate layout for the email, but at the moment I cannot render the view in the way that t is after charts have been generated. Charts are generated with probably jQuery, but when I render them they still contains jQuery and not only tags

Comment: Well as you said, the charts only work with JavaScript and JavaScript won't be supported in an email. As a result, there's no way to make this solution work. You'll have to use another charting solution, probably something on the backend that can generate the charts as images.

Comment: I need to disagree with you, as when I run my dashboard and check the source code the charts are without jQuery, only html tags. So there must by a way to fully render the page and then save it to a string, I just didn't find how yet :)

Comment: Unfortunately charts are still in jQuery format. I think I will try to do a screenshot of the page using phantomjs and than send it.

Comment: I tried @Whistler ! :-( Sorry I couldn't have helped more.